# How to connect with DB2 client in windows.?

Tags: db2, client-server, db2-luw, db2-connect

I have installed 'DB2 data server client' on my machine. I want to connect to it and execute the shell script, but i am getting error `DB21061E  Command line environment not initialized` , when i am executing shell script and trying to connect with it.
I have installed DB2 version '11.5' and Fix Pack "0".
what should be the fix for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use some unix environment on Windows to run .sh file? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

This is a frequently asked question.

If you are running on Microsoft-Windows then you **either** run scripts for Db2 in a db2cmd.exe window, or set the environment variable DB2CLP correctly before running your scripts.

For Microsoft-Windows, You can run `db2cwadmin`  to open the `db2cmd.exe` window. This window will already have the environment variable DB2CLP set.  You can also directly run the `db2cmd.exe` program if `db2cwadmin` is not available.

For Powershell:  `set-item -path env:DB2CLP -value "**$$**"`

Apart from setting the DB2CLP environment variable, and/or using the db2cmd.exe window, you then need to perform additional configuration steps called "catalog node"  and "catalog database"  before you will be able to connect via command-line or db2-clp.

If the Db2 database server is remote (not on your machine), then you need to catalog the node to tell the Db2-client about the hostname-port for the Db2-server. `db2 catalog tcpip node`  see documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001944.html), followed by the command `db2 terminate`.

IF you do not want to catalog, then you can still connect at the command line but with the `[clpplus][2]` tool (a java application), which accepts a connection-string and allows an Oracle SQL*plus style interface to Db2 databases.

If the Db2-node is already catalogued correctly, or if the database is local (on the same hostname as your Db2-client), then you need to run `db2 catalog database...`  command, see documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001936.html) and then run `db2 terminate`.